# How to show only part of text in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, list, checkboxlist

I'm creating an `WindowsForms` application that is using a list of persons with 4 parameters (ID, Name, Surname, Permissions):

```
public List<Osoba> ListaOsoba()
        {
            Osoba nr1 = new Osoba(1, "Name", "Surname", Permissions.Administrator);
            Osoba nr2 = new Osoba(2, "Name2", "Surname2", Permissions.Użytkownik);
            Osoba nr3 = new Osoba(3, "Name3", "Surname3", Permissions.Użytkownik);
            listaOsób.Add(nr1);
            listaOsób.Add(nr2);
            listaOsób.Add(nr3);

            return listaOsób;
        }
```

I would like to post all those Parameters to `CheckedListBox`, but show only name and surname to the user. The ID and Permissions should be hidden, but they need to exist, because I want to use them later.

Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static bool CheckBoxListPopulate(CheckBoxList CbList, IList<T> liSource, string TextFiled, string ValueField)
    {
        try
        {

            CbList.Items.Clear();
            if (liSource.Count > 0)
            {
                CbList.DataSource = liSource;
                CbList.DataTextField = TextFiled;
                CbList.DataValueField = ValueField;
                CbList.DataBind();
                return true;
            }
            else { return false; }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

1. here Cb list is the control name  and
2. List item Ilist is the list source name
3. Text field (should be concatination ) ="Name" + "Surname"
4. Value field will be Hidden it can be "1,2,3"

so only Text field will be visible to user

Answer (score 0):

To bind only name and surname to checkedboxlist first store name and surname together and then try this:

```
NameS = "Name" + "Surname";

((ListBox)checkedListBox).DataSource = listaOsób;
((ListBox)checkedListBox).DisplayMember = "NameS";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, here you have to make arbitrary compound properties for display and value member like DisplayName and HiddenId and then you can easily bound with checkedlistbox.

```
public class Osoba
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Permissions Permission { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string HiddenId { get; set; }
    public Osoba()
    { }
    public Osoba(int id, string fname, string lname, Permissions p)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = fname;
        LastName = lname;
        Permission = p;
        DisplayName = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        HiddenId = Id + "_" + Permission.GetHashCode();
    }
    public void ListaOsoba()
    {
        List<Osoba> objList = new List<Osoba>();
        Osoba nr1 = new Osoba(1, "Name", "Surname", Permissions.Administrator);
        Osoba nr2 = new Osoba(2, "Name2", "Surname2", Permissions.Uzytkownik);
        Osoba nr3 = new Osoba(3, "Name3", "Surname3", Permissions.Uzytkownik);
        objList.Add(nr1);
        objList.Add(nr2);
        objList.Add(nr3);

        ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DataSource = objList;
        ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
        ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).ValueMember = "HiddenId";
        MessageBox.Show(((ListBox)checkedListBox1).Text);
        MessageBox.Show(((ListBox)checkedListBox1).SelectedValue.ToString());

    }
}
public enum Permissions
{
    Administrator,
    Uzytkownik
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing with SQL. I returned many columns, but only wanted one to show.
Anyway

```
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

            foreach (object o in ListaOsoba)
            {
                arr.Items.Add(o[1].ToString()+" "+o[2].ToString());
            }

            foreach (var item in arr)
            {
                chkNames.Items.Add(arr.ToString()); //chkNames is your CheckListBox
            }
```

Then later when querying which ID and such goes where, loop through you original list, and see who was ticked based on the name and surname combo, find the ID related to that person and you should be sorted